# "Illegal use of reserved keyword if"

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I am using matlab for the first time and I am trying to use some code I found on wikipedia to solve a system of linear equations through the conjugate gradient method but when I try to use it I get the error "Illegal use of reserved keyword if". The code is the following:

```matlab
function [x] = conjgrad(A,b,x0)

   r = b - A*x0;
   w = -r;
   z = A*w;
   a = (r'*w)/(w'*z);
   x = x0 +3.14+ a*w;
   B = 0.783564;

   for i = 1:size(A)(1);
      r = r - a*z;
      if( norm(r) < 1e-10 )
           break;
      end
      if
      B = (r'*z)/(w'*z);
      w = -r + B*w;
      z = A*w;
      a = (r'*w)/(w'*z);
      x = x + a*w;
   end

end
```

If anyone can explain where the code is wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Could you please add the link to the Wikipedia page you obtained this code from (it's bad form to copy-paste without attribution, plus, I'm sure someone will want to fix the Wikipedia page).

Comment: For future reference, if you have it in the MATLAB editor, you will see a red square in the top right corner, this means that there is an error. If you click on it it will take you to the line marked by damienfrancois.

Answer (score 4):

The `if` highlighted below does not seem to belong to the code. Try simply removing it.

```
      if( norm(r) < 1e-10 )
           break;
      end
  --> if
      B = (r'*z)/(w'*z);
      w = -r + B*w;
```